# android sms: how to create voice sms to send as text message

Tags: android, sms, speech-to-text

i have tried the code for converting speech to text, now i want that this converted text can be send as SMS please give me help i use the code of viral petal for speech to text conversion
and used speech to text using API

Answer (score 1):

public void readExcelData(Context context, String filename){

```
try {
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    Vector cellVe
```

### c

torHolder = new Vector();

```
    /** Create a POIFSFileSystem object**/

    POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new
        POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
    /** Create a workbook using the File System**/

    HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new
        HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
    /** Get the first sheet from workbook**/

    HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    /** We now need something to 
        iterate through the cells.**/

    Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
    while(rowIter.hasNext())
    {
        HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
        Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
        Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
        while(cellIter.hasNext()){
        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
        cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);


    }
    cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);

}
    excelTableLayout.removeAllViews();
    android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    for(int i=0;i<cellVectorHolder.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Nama: "+cellVectorHolder.elementAt(i));
        String values = cellVectorHolder.elementAt(i)+"";
        String valuesArr[] = values.split(",");
        String first = valuesArr[0];
        String sec = valuesArr[1];
        System.out.println("\n");
        TableRow row = new TableRow(ctx);

        TextView firstValues = new TextView(ctx);
        firstValues.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        firstValues.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        firstValues.setText(valuesArr[0].substring(1));
        firstValues.setTextSize(17);
        firstValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.excelformatbackground);
        firstValues.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        firstValues.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
        firstValues.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView secondValues = new TextView(ctx);
        secondValues.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        secondValues.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        secondValues.setText(valuesArr[1]);
        secondValues.setTextSize(17);
        secondValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.excelformatbackground);
        secondValues.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        secondValues.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
        secondValues.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView thirdValues = new TextView(ctx);
        thirdValues.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        thirdValues.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        thirdValues.setText(valuesArr[2]);
        thirdValues.setTextSize(17);
        thirdValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.excelformatbackground);
        thirdValues.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        thirdValues.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));
        thirdValues.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView fourthValues = new TextView(ctx);
        fourthValues.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        fourthValues.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        fourthValues.setText(valuesArr[3].substring(0,valuesArr[3].length() - 1));
        fourthValues.setTextSize(17);
        fourthValues.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.excelformatbackground);
        fourthValues.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        fourthValues.setLayoutParams(params);

        row.addView(firstValues);
        row.addView(secondValues);
        row.addView(thirdValues);
        row.addView(fourthValues);
        excelTableLayout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }

System.out.println("Data is "+cellVectorHolder);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}